# How do I refactor to wait for the AJAX queries to finish before exporting to CSV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the code below triggered by button click. When I run it, the CSV is created but is empty. The `console.log(rows)` output is as expected, but has a note saying `Value below was evaluated just now.`

How do I make the execution of `exportToCsv` wait until the AJAX calls are complete?

```
$("#downloadBtn").click(function() {
    weeks = getWeeks(startDate.val(), endDate.val());
    // start downloading the data
    for (i=0; i< weeks.length; i++) {
        // contains $.ajax query that appends to "rows"
        fetchDataWeek( weeks[i][0], weeks[i][1] );  
    }
    console.log(rows);
    exportToCsv( fileName, rows );            
});
```

Edit in response to [surajck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42817932/1706564):

In addition to the suggested code using `Promises`, I've edited my `fetchDataWeek` function as follows, but when I run it I get `Uncaught TypeError: Promise resolver undefined is not a function`.

```
function fetchDataWeek( startDay, endDay ) {
    startDay = makeDateString(startDay);
    endDay = makeDateString(endDay);
    url = "https://api" + startDay + endDay + ".json";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(result){
            parseHistory(result);
            _promise.resolve(result);
        }
    });            
}
```

Comment: Execute `exportToCsv` in your callback.

Comment: You mean you are firing ajax queries inside a `for` loop? In that case, you'll need to create an array of `Promises`, one for each `ajax`. And then execute `exportToCsv` when all of them have resolved

Comment: @surajck, what would that look like? This is literally day 1 of jQuery for me

Comment: @surajck, or is there a better way to structure this than the for loop?

Comment: In its simplest form, you would increase a counter inside the callback function of the asynchronous request, and if that counter has reached the number of requests, you call the export function. But you might want to react to errors as well, otherwise your export might never start if one of the requests fails for whatever reason. Promises would be an a little more advanced way of doing it.

Comment: @JamieBull, I have added my suggestion as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is some generic code to help you understand:

```
$("#downloadBtn").click(function() {
    weeks = getWeeks(startDate.val(), endDate.val());
    // start downloading the data

    // Create an array to hold all your promises
    var promiseArray = [];

    for (i=0; i< weeks.length; i++) {
        // contains $.ajax query that appends to "rows"
        var _promise = Q.defer(); // Create a promise (using https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

        // send this promise to the ajax callback
        fetchDataWeek( weeks[i][0], weeks[i][1], _promise );
        promiseArray.push(_promise)  // Push this promise into the array
    }

    Promise.all(promiseArray).then( function () { // Wait for all promises to resolve
        console.log(rows);
        exportToCsv( fileName, rows );
    })            
});
```

Your `fetchDataWeek` code then becomes:

```
function fetchDataWeek( startDay, endDay, _promise ) {
    startDay = makeDateString(startDay);
    endDay = makeDateString(endDay);
    url = "https://api" + startDay + endDay + ".json";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(result){
            parseHistory(result);
            _promise.resolve(result); // resolving that promise here
        },
        error: function (error) {
            _promise.reject(error) // rejecting it in case of error
        }
    });            
}
```

Comment: This is not the exact code, the syntax of the `Promise` statements will differ with the library you use.

Comment: Looking into that now. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure it's the right way to go but I'm getting an error. I've edited the question to add details

Comment: Hey , I suggest you use a promise library. Try this: https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: @JamieBull did you remember to load the javascript for he promise library? I posted an example of using promises with JQuery, taken from working code I had in front of me.

Comment: @JamieBull, I have edited my answer to suit the updated question

Comment: Ok, I'm now getting no errors, but the CSV only has the headers written to it. `_promise` is being resolved before `parseHistory` has finished writing to rows.

Comment: Ok so `parseHistory` also has async stuff going on inside it ? Lol! Anyway, pass the `_promise` into `parseHistory` too, and resolve it deep inside it!

Comment: -1.                                                                          Passing `_promise` into `fetchDataWeek` is an absolutely horrible pattern.

Comment: @Bergi, kindly share why, and also what my alternatives are in such scenarios. (I have used this pattern a few times, and want to know the pitfalls)

Comment: Passing in a deferred is like an output parameter - instead, one should use return values, and always return a promise from an asynchronous function. The promise should be created inside the function from which it is returned. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42823970/1048572) for a revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX calls are asynchronous. Your code executes before the data is loaded. To prevent this, you should use a callback function and perform any manipulations with data loaded with AJAX there and nowhere else.

Comment: I understand this, but I'm not sure how I would refactor so that all of the AJAX calls are complete before the `exportToCsv`.

Comment: What exactly are you querying with AJAX? Is it a PHP script? If yes, I would move the loop to PHP and output the desired array there, so you need just one AJAX call and can execute whatever you want in the callback function.

Comment: No, it's an external API that I don't control and can only access one week at a time

Comment: In that case, surajck proposed an excellent solution above, use that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery a promise looks like this (using basic auth to access the endpoint, which is secured):

```
      var url = "/myEndpoint/";       

      var req = $.ajax
      ({
        type: "GET",

        xhrFields: 
        {
          withCredentials: true
        },
        headers: 
        {
          'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(gAccountName + ':' + gAccountPw)
        },
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json'
    });

    req.done(function(data)
    {
      // The data var has your results
      // process here

      console.log(data);          


    });

    req.fail(function(data)
    {

      alert("There was an error loading your list of names. Please try again in a few seconds."); 
    });
  }
```