# Why is no value returned from my Promise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, q

In this slightly reduced code, one or more weeks of observations are downloaded a week at a time from an API, and aggregated into `rows` and exported to CSV. At least that is the idea. What is actually happening is that an `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined` is raised in the (not shown) `exportToCsv` function because the `_promise` pushed from `promiseArray` to `rows` is coming out as `undefined`. What am I missing?

```
$("#downloadBtn").click(function() {
    weeks = getWeeks(startDate.val(), endDate.val());  // array like [[startDay1, endDay1], [startDay2, endDay2], ...]
    // start downloading the data
    var promiseArray = [];
    for (i=0; i< weeks.length; i++) {
        var _promise = Q.defer();
        fetchDataWeek( weeks[i][0], weeks[i][1], _promise );
        promiseArray.push(_promise)  // Push this promise into the array
    }
    Promise.all(promiseArray).then( function () { // Wait for all promises to resolve
        var rows = [headers];
        for (i=0; i < promiseArray.length; i++) {
            rows.push(promiseArray[i]);
        }
        exportToCsv( fileName, rows );
    })
});

function fetchDataWeek( startDay, endDay, _promise ) {
    url = "https://api" + startDay + endDay + ".json";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(result){
            var weekRows = parseHistory(result);
            _promise.resolve(weekRows);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            _promise.reject(error) // rejecting it in case of error
        }
    });            
}

// Extract all data from a query response
function parseHistory(data) {
    var weekRows = [];
    var days = data.history.days;
    for (var i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
        dayRows = formatDay( days[i] );
        for (var j= 0; j < dayRows.length; j++) {
            weekRows.push(dayRows[j]);
        }
    }
    return weekRows;
}
```

Comment: I think your main problem is that `_promise` is **not** a promise but a [deferred object](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#using-deferreds). You need `promiseArray.push(_promise.promise)`. Why are you using `Q` **and** native `Promise`?

Comment: From [this answer to an earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42817932/1706564). I'm totally new to jQuery and promises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A promise is not a magical object that "becomes" a different value when it is resolved. When you were doing `rows.push(promiseArray[i]);`, you were collecting promise objects not the results that they contained.

To access the result that a promise was or will be fulfilled with, you need to chain a `.then(…)` callback to it in which you can access the result as the parameter. To collect the results from all the promises in the array, you use `Promise.all`, which returns another promise that not only waits for all the input promises but also fulfills with an array of their result values.

```
$("#downloadBtn").click(function() {
    var weeks = getWeeks(startDate.val(), endDate.val());
    // start downloading the data
    var promiseArray = weeks.map(function(week) { // map is simpler than a loop with `push`
        return fetchDataWeek( week[0], week[1] );
    })
    Promise.all(promiseArray).then( function(results) { // Wait for all promises to resolve
        var rows = [headers].concat(results);
        exportToCsv( fileName, rows );
    })
});

function fetchDataWeek( startDay, endDay, _promise ) {
    var url = "https://api" + startDay + endDay + ".json";
    var jQpromise = $.ajax({
        url: url
    });
    var qPromise = Q(jQpromise);
    return qPromise.then(parseHistory);
}

function parseHistory(data) {
    var weekRows = [];
    var days = data.history.days;
    for (var i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
        var dayRows = formatDay( days[i] );
        for (var j= 0; j < dayRows.length; j++) {
            weekRows.push(dayRows[j]);
        }
    }
    return weekRows;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can receive the result of your promises in the `then` handler:

```
Promise.all(promiseArray).then( function (results) { // Wait for all promises to resolve
    var rows = [headers].concat(results);
    exportToCsv( fileName, rows );
  })
```